# ERR Error: End of data reached (data length = 0, asked index = 4). Corrupted zip?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, whatsapp, exceljs

im making a whatsapp bot, im saving the chats in a excel file (im using exceljs) to read and handle some responses, i prefer to use promises and resolve them, i have a function to read chats:

```js
const readChat = (number, message, step = null) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      number = number.replace("@c.us", "");
      number = `${number}@c.us`;
      const pathExcel = `./chats/${number}.xlsx`;
      const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
      const today = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm");

      if (fs.existsSync(pathExcel)) {
        const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        workbook.xlsx
          .readFile(pathExcel)
          .then(() => {
            const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
            const lastRow = worksheet.lastRow;
            let getRowInsert = worksheet.getRow(++lastRow.number);
            getRowInsert.getCell("A").value = today;
            getRowInsert.getCell("B").value = message;

            if (step) {
              getRowInsert.getCell("C").value = step;
            }

            getRowInsert.commit();
            workbook.xlsx
              .writeFile(pathExcel)
              .then(() => {
                const getRowPrevStep = worksheet.getRow(lastRow.number);
                const lastStep = getRowPrevStep.getCell("C").value;
                resolve(lastStep);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("ERR", err);
                reject("error");
              });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERR", err);
            reject("error");
          });
      } else {
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Chats");
        worksheet.columns = [
          { header: "Fecha", key: "number_customer" },
          { header: "Mensajes", key: "message" },
          { header: "Paso", key: "step" },
        ];

        step = step || "";

        worksheet.addRow([today, message, step]);
        workbook.xlsx
          .writeFile(pathExcel)
          .then(() => {
            resolve("STEP_1");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error", err);
            reject("error");
          });
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
```

but the code after that else, its giving me the error: ERR Error: End of data reached (data length = 0, asked index = 4). Corrupted zip ?, the else, is supposed to be executed when there is no excel saved with that chat. I searched in many questions and pages, but i have not found any solution

Answer (score 1):

in my case install jszip

```
npm i jszip
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would get this error after you stop your execution in between, i.e when the file is getting updated and this would corrupt the excel file.

You could try adding a "try catch" around read file in your if condition and create a new copy of workbook whenever you get these particular errors ('End of data reached (data length = 0, asked index = 4). Corrupted zip ?' or 'File not found:')

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue on frontend, in my case the file was corrupted. Try open it in excel.